# Prevent large image uploads

Tags: images, uploads

I want to prevent users in my blog from uploading large size images. And I mean large in px size not MB. Max Upload is set to 8MB which should be ok but I wan't to prevent uploading for images larger than 3000x3000px.

Is there any hook I am missing that I could write a function for to tell users their image is too large?

Comment: You can try taking a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_constrain_size_for_editor but this will only help constrain for the text editor. If you want to keep people from uploading huge files to the media library, you can try a plugin. I've tried this one before and it's worked nicely: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-image-size-limit/ Also tried this one to reduce sizes already on the server: http://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a few different solutions available here:

### Automatically scaling down

If you just do not want to store huge amounts of image data on your webspace, I'd recommend the Plugin [Imsanity](http://wordpress.org/plugins/imsanity/). This automatically scales down the uploaded images, even if they are too big.

### Forbid large uploads

In this case the user has more work to do, as they will have to scale down the images on their own. You could filter the `wp_handle_upload_prefilter`:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'f711_image_size_prevent');
function f711_image_size_prevent($file) {
    $size = $file['size'];
    $size = $size / 1024; // Calculate down to KB
    $type = $file['type'];
    $is_image = strpos($type, 'image');
    $limit = 5000; // Your Filesize in KB

    if ( ( $size > $limit ) && ($is_image !== false) ) {
        $file['error'] = 'Image files must be smaller than '.$limit.'KB';
    }

    return $file;

}
```

### Change the PHP values

This one is fairly straight forward, you just have to set `max_upload_size` in your `.htaccess` or `php.ini`.

Comment: used version 2 to prevent image size AND image dimensions. As size wasn't always the problem. I already set max_upload_size to 8M but still some images with large dimensions were uploaded