# Wordpress function: limit size, only jpg, jpeg, limit of uploaded files per account

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

Need help with a function that will limit upload for non admins:

1. Check before upload if file is jpg, jpeg.
2. Check before upload if picture is not bigger than 700kb.
3. Limit uploaded files to 7 per normal user WordPress account.

I was searching for plugin or function that will be able to do this but no luck :(

Is it even possible to check the file before upload in wordpress?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot check the image before uploading, as WordPress is a serverside script.

However, before inserting the image in the Media library, you have different options, as I explained in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131076/15680), with filtering `wp_handle_upload_prefilter`.

In your case, the function filtering the `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` would be something like this:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'f711_image_size_prevent');
function f711_image_size_prevent($file) {

    // get filesize of upload
    $size = $file['size'];
    $size = $size / 1024; // Calculate down to KB

    // get imagetype of upload
    $type = $file['type'];
    $is_image = strpos($type, 'image');

    // set sizelimit
    $limit = 700; // Your Filesize in KB

    // set imagelimit
    $imagelimit = 7;

    // set allowed imagetype
    $imagetype = 'image/jpeg';

    // query how many images the current user already uploaded
    global $current_user;
    $args = array(
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'numberposts'     => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'attachment',
        'author'          => $current_user->ID,
    );
    $attachmentsbyuser = get_posts( $args );

    if ( ( $size > $limit ) && ($is_image !== false) ) { // check if the image is small enough
        $file['error'] = 'Image files must be smaller than '.$limit.'KB';
    } elseif ( $type != $imagetype ) { // check if image type is allowed
        $file['error'] = 'Image must be ' . $imagetype . '.';
    } elseif ( count( $attachmentsbyuser ) >= $imagelimit ) { // check if the user has exceeded the image limit
        $file['error'] = 'Image limit of ' . $imagelimit . ' is exceeded for this user.';
    }
    return $file;

}
```

Comment: Hello thank You very much You are the best ! and it's working one more question what is: $size = $size / 1024; // Calculate down to KB

Comment: This is just to compare KB to KB. You could also skip this line and enter your filsizelimit in Bytes. I prefer KB because the numbers do not get that big.

Comment: Ok thank You for fast answer and the code is working !!! Again thank You. One more question do You know how hide this option "Regenerate thumbnails" in wp-admin/upload.php from non admin users ?

Comment: Hm, this seems to be added by a Plugin. This Plugin does not need to be activated all the time, does it? Try deactivating it after regenerating your thumbnails.

Comment: One more question fischi hot to make it work only for subscriber users ?

Comment: Just put it all into a conditional, and pick a capability the subscriber does not possess: `if ( current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) )`

Comment: Something like this ?

if ( current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) {
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'f711_image_size_prevent');
function f711_image_size_prevent($file) {

    // get filesize of upload
    $size = $file['size'];code...

...return $file;
}

}

sorry i am not so good with php

Comment: Yeah, you can add the filter just with the conditional, like `if ( current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) { add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'f711_image_size_prevent'); }` the rest can stay the same.

Comment: Hmm changed it like You posted and it still show me i have used limit 5 images as admin logged.

Comment: sorry- it should of course be `if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) )`, my bad!

Comment: I did `if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'f711_image_size_prevent');
function f711_image_size_prevent($file) {` ... and the rest of the code and it not working admin and subscriber can add as many they want

Comment: Ok i have changed `'edit_post'` to `'moderate_comments'` and it's working thank You

Comment: Yes, nice! I did not know how your capabilities were set on your site, so `edit_post` was just an example. HAve fun!

Comment: Thank you @fischi for helping here. I have changed the code a bit (since I do not know much about php) and I always get exceeded the limit. If I remove the lines about the limit upload, everything works fine.