# How to check if uploaded file is .pdf not .jpeg?

Tags: uploads

I use [a function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/133527/25187) in my theme that prevents upload of big size image files (thanks to @fischi), but I want to apply it **strictly** to .jpg/.jpeg files only, because it prevents to upload .pdf files too. How to adapt this function?

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'f711_image_size_prevent');
function f711_image_size_prevent($file) {

    // get filesize of upload
    $size = $file['size'];
    $size = $size / 1024; // Calculate down to KB

    // get imagetype of upload
    $type = $file['type'];
    $is_image = strpos($type, 'image');

    // set sizelimit
    $limit = 700; // Your Filesize in KB

    // set imagelimit
    $imagelimit = 7;

    // set allowed imagetype
    $imagetype = 'image/jpeg';

    // query how many images the current user already uploaded
    global $current_user;
    $args = array(
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'numberposts'     => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'attachment',
        'author'          => $current_user->ID,
    );
    $attachmentsbyuser = get_posts( $args );

    if ( ( $size > $limit ) && ($is_image !== false) ) { // check if the image is small enough
        $file['error'] = 'Image files must be smaller than '.$limit.'KB';
    } elseif ( $type != $imagetype ) { // check if image type is allowed
        $file['error'] = 'Image must be ' . $imagetype . '.';
    } elseif ( count( $attachmentsbyuser ) >= $imagelimit ) { // check if the user has exceeded the image limit
        $file['error'] = 'Image limit of ' . $imagelimit . ' is exceeded for this user.';
    }
    return $file;

}
```

**UPDATE**

This is the improved code (not tested yet), thanks to @nikhil-sheth:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'f711_image_size_prevent');
function f711_image_size_prevent($file) {

    // get imagetype of upload
    $type = $file['type'];
    $is_image = strpos($type, 'image');

    // set allowed imagetype
    $imagetype = 'image/jpeg';

    if ( $type == $imagetype ) {

        // get filesize of upload
        $size = $file['size'];
        $size = $size / 1024; // Calculate down to KB

        // set sizelimit
        $limit = 700; // Your Filesize in KB

        // set imagelimit
        $imagelimit = 7;

        // query how many images the current user already uploaded
        global $current_user;
        $args = array(
            'orderby'         => 'post_date',
            'order'           => 'DESC',
            'numberposts'     => -1,
            'post_type'       => 'attachment',
            'author'          => $current_user->ID,
        );
        $attachmentsbyuser = get_posts( $args );

        if ( ( $size > $limit ) && ($is_image !== false) ) { // check if the image is small enough
            $file['error'] = 'Image files must be smaller than '.$limit.'KB';
        } elseif ( count( $attachmentsbyuser ) >= $imagelimit ) { // check if the user has exceeded the image limit
            $file['error'] = 'Image limit of ' . $imagelimit . ' is exceeded for this user.';
        }
        return $file;
    } else { return $file; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the following:

First I initiate an array of supported mime types:

`$supportedTypes = array( 'application/pdf' );`

Next I get my actual uploaded file type:

`$fileType = $_FILES['type'][0]`

Then I use [`wp_check_filetype()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_filetype) to get the extension and mimetype: `$fileArray = wp_check_filetype( basename( $_FILES['name'][0] ) );`

Finally I run a conditional to make sure that the uploaded mimetype is in my supported array:

`if( in_array( $fileArray['type'], $supportedTypes ) ) {`

IF the conditional is true you can proceed with your upload, otherwise the file won't upload and you can bail out.

Answer (score -1):

In below code we find out mime type of uploaded file. Then using switch case we check mime type of uploaded file is  application/pdf or not.

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$ok = false;
switch ($mime) {
   case 'application/pdf';
        $ok = true;
   default:
       die("Unknown/not permitted file type");
}
```

Comment: Hi Pallavi, can you please edit your post to explain _how_ this answers the question, and what the code does? Code only answers are discouraged. Thanks.

Comment: Downvoted due to lack of context, seems like you do not want to learn or take advice from us. I will keep downvoting your answers as poor quality. I'm not going to comment on all your posts and ask you to add **PROPER**  explanations to your code

Answer (score -3):

lurie add below condition...

```
if ( $type == $imagetype ) {
// write code for reduce .jpg/.jpeg files size or call function here
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code

Comment: @nikhil-sheth Thanks! I edited the question because of some errors and added an improved code with your suggestion. What you think, is this correct?